# consuming JSON POST data in an Express application

Tags: node.js, express

I am sending this JSON file to my node js server :

```
{
"try": "this"
}
```

I sent it using Postman (chrome extension) like this:
[image: Postman example]

I'm trying to log this data from the server, I am using node js & express framework.
In the main app.js I used:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/update/:id', app_object.update);
```

And in the **app_object** router:

```
exports.update = function ( req, res, next ){
    var postedObject = req.body;
    console.log(postedObject);
    res.send('Handle Post');
};
```

When I send the Post request I am getting from the server only '{}'.
Can someone explain what's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: what version of express do you use? 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: I ran express --version and got 4.2.0 version.

Comment: As far as I know `express --version` outputs version of express-generator utility, not Express itself. If you want to view installed Express version, you may find it in `node_modules/express/package.json` file. As for your question -- try using [`body-parser` middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)